# How to change sorter param in Yii2 / GridView?I

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I have two tables with farily same names of the columns, usinng two different search models (both using `ActiveDataProvider`'s) so when I sort one by a column, the other gets affected as well.

I have tried setting this in my second `GridView`:

```
'sorter' => [
    'class' => 'yii\widgets\LinkSorter',
    'sortParam' => 'sortB',
],
```

But with no avail.

---

**EDIT:** Sort param is a GET variable passed to server: `?sort=amount`, or `?param=1&sort=created_at`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`$sortParam`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sort.html#$sortParam-detail) is a property of `yii\data\Sort`, which handles the sorting on the DataProvider level and is accessable via [$dataProvider->sort](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-basedataprovider.html#$sort-detail).
The [`$sorter`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-baselistview.html#$sorter-detail) on the GridView is only a widget that can display the sorting links, but that is inherited from `BaseListView` and not displayed in GridView by default.

You should set this property on the DataProvider like this:

```
$dataProvider->sort->sortParam = 'user-sort';
```

The same applies to the `pageParam` too.
There is a section in the guide about [Multiple GridViews on one page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#multiple-gridviews-on-one-page) covering exactly this topic.